# django rich text field data in email

Tags: html, django, email, rtf

I want to send Post data of a RTF Field (Rich text field) or a HTML Field data in a email, below are my code and it seems to be not happening, please guide me.

**models.py**

```
class Servicereport(models.Model):
            name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
            customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
            email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
            report = RichTextField(default='<p><b>sample data .... </b>')
    
    
class Customer(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ServicereportForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Servicereport
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
        'report': RichTextFormField()
        }
```

**views.py**

```
def createServicereport(request):
    form = ServicereportForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ServicereportForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = "SERVICE REPORT"
            html_message = render_to_string('report')
            message = EmailMessage(subject, html_message, 'from@email.com', [request.POST.get('email')])
            message.content_subtype = 'html'
            message.send()
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'service_report.html', context)
```

I want to send POST data of RTF Field 'report" via email and the code will be in HTML, but I am unable to send, it is showing below error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /create_service_report/
report
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/create_service_report/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
report
Exception Location: D:\development\website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Python Executable:  D:\development\website\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.9
```

Comment: The error is because you've got the report variable as a string inside `render_to_string('report')`, so it's looking for the template `report`
but isn't `report` already a string?- this call might not even be necessary -> `html_message = report`

Comment: Yes, it is working, Thank you very much.
html_message = request.POST.get('report')

Comment: You could also use `html_message = form.report`, and that would be after Django's form validates it (possibly cleans it?)

Comment: Thanks, I have one more question, hope you dont mind answering it. 

If I have to call the "TO" email ID from another model like customer.email, what will be my syntax and views.py ?

Comment: I assume the "to" means the `[request.POST.get('email')]` inside of `EmailMessage`? It depends. If it's hardcoded you'd just do a `[request.POST.get('email'), Customer.objects.get(name='Cust1').email]`, otherwise you'd use some data posted in the `.get()` (or better yet a `.filter().first()`) ..it's hard to give a definitive answer as I don't know the specifics

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have edited my question and added Customer model. In the same scenario, instead of sending email to request.POST.get('email') email field from Servicereport model, I want to send email to email field from Customer model, how do i make changes to my views.py ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252846/discussion-between-john-doe-and-nealium).